# Swift: Getting error "Value of option type not unwrapped" on copying files to new project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am migrating few of my Swift files from an one project to other. Both the projects are built in Objective C. I have followed all the steps for adding Swift files to the new project and Xcode generated the Bridging Header too.

The old project compiles and runs fine, but on compiling the new one I am getting error "Value of option type not unwrapped" in some of the swift files, I cleaned the project several times and deleted Derived Folder too, but still it doesn't compiles.

Is there anything I could have missed?

Comment: Your code might be using optional variables where an unwrapped optional is expected. Check where you are getting the errors and add a ! to the variable. To be safe better to use optional binding feature of swift to safely  unwrap the values wherever required.

Comment: But the same code compiles successfully in other project...

Comment: If you are migrating from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.1 then you could get these errors in places where it was not erring in the past because in Swift 1.2 it was expecting an optional value but in Swift 2.1 it might be expecting an unwrapped value. You will have to check where you are getting these errors and solve them individually. Can you give a sample of where you are getting the error not but in the other project?

Comment: dont use the ! just to correct the errors, use someObject?.someProperty, and if you need to check it first then use the if let

Comment: Thank Guys, I found the problem... There are few CoreData files in new project with objects marked as "nullable", and that is where my swift code fails, as nullable values needs to be unwrapped...